# How do i exclude namespace functions when iterating over an enum?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, namespaces

I have the following code

```
export enum JournalEntryType {
    ORDINARY_JOURNAL_ENTRY = 'ORDINARY_JOURNAL_ENTRY',
    PLANT_TRANSPLANTED = 'PLANT_TRANSPLANTED',
    SOW_SEEDS = 'SOW_SEEDS',
    SEEDS_GERMINATED = 'SEEDS_GERMINATED',
    PLANT_BLOSSOMS = 'PLANT_BLOSSOMS',
    FRUIT_SETTING = 'FRUIT_SETTING',
    FRUIT_CHANGED_COLOR = 'FRUIT_CHANGED_COLOR',
    HARVEST = 'HARVEST',
    ANIMAL_SIGHTING = 'ANIMAL_SIGHTING'
}

export namespace JournalEntryType{
    export function getJournalEntryTypeColor(journalEntryType: string): string{
        switch(journalEntryType){
            case JournalEntryType.ORDINARY_JOURNAL_ENTRY.toString(): return '#FFFFFF';
            case JournalEntryType.PLANT_TRANSPLANTED.toString(): return '#8B4513';
            case JournalEntryType.SOW_SEEDS.toString(): return '#D2691E';
            case JournalEntryType.SEEDS_GERMINATED.toString(): return '#7CFC00';
            case JournalEntryType.PLANT_BLOSSOMS.toString(): return '#FFB6C1';
            case JournalEntryType.FRUIT_SETTING.toString(): return '#FF69B4';
            case JournalEntryType.FRUIT_CHANGED_COLOR.toString(): return '#ff1493';
            case JournalEntryType.HARVEST.toString(): return '#DC143C';
            case JournalEntryType.ANIMAL_SIGHTING.toString(): return '#800080';
            default: throw new Error();
        }
    }
}
```

When i iterate over `JournalEntryType` and log every value like so:

```
for(let journalType in JournalEntryType){
    console.log(journalType);
}
```

The last value that is printed won't be `ANIMAL_SIGHTING` but `getJournalEntryTypeColor`. In other words, it also iterates over any functions that are declared in the `namespace`. How do i prevent this from happening? I've tried filtering out the method with an if statement that checks whether the type of the `journalType`is a string. But that won't stop from `getJournalEntryTypeColor` getting printed as well.

Comment: Personally I'd be inclined to use different names for the enum and the namespace, but if you want them the same then you might be able to filter out the function with something like `typeof(JournalEntryType[journalType]) === 'function'` (I've not tested it). i.e. checking the type of `JournalEntryType[journalType]` rather than the type of `journalType`.

Comment: @Tim using the following code `Object.keys(JournalEntryType).filter(journalType => !(typeof(JournalEntryType[journalType]) === 'function')).forEach(journalType => { //code});` works like a charm, thank you for the suggestion. If you want you can turn your comment into an answer and then i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is that you need to check the type of the property on the object, not the type of the key.

```
Object.keys(JournalEntryType)
    .filter(journalType => !(typeof(JournalEntryType[journalType]) === 'function'))
    .forEach(journalType => { 
        //code here
    });
```

(This code is taken from the comments, it was written by Maurice.)